# IOS/Autolayout: Make UILabel go to more than one line with Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I need to get a `UILabel` to go to more than one line if text requires with autolayout.  In code and also in storyboard for good measure I have set numberOfLines to 0 and wordwrapping on and I've also called `sizeToFit`.

The full amount of text will display on multiple lines if I set the height constraint for the label to a large enough value such = 200.  But with short text, it does not contract, leaving a lot of white space.  But if I set the height constraint to a lower value such as >=21 then it shows only one line and cuts off everything else.

The view hierarchy is View-Scrollview-Contentview-elements  I set a bottom constant for the lowest element with a priority of 250 so it should adjust. Autolayout shows no errors

Nothing, however, short of creating a huge height constraint for the label lets the label extend to multiple lines.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this issue.

In viewwillappear:

```
_myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;//deprecated but I threw it in too
_myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
_myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[_myLabel sizeToFit];

// height constraint for label

height>=21//text does not extend more than one line
height=200//text does extend more than one line but leaves lots of whitespace if text is short ie it does not shrink.
```

Answer (score 0):

from Storyboard ,

- Set property

  ```
  _myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
  ```
- Set constraint

  ```
  _myLabel.height <= 200
  ```

**Note :** label height will automatically set according to its text content. From constraint relationship label height is atmost `200` and atleast height is its text content (automatically adjustable).

Now still any doubt then ask.

Comment: when I set it to <=200, label disappears entirely

Comment: @user6631314 If there in no text in label then its height is zero else it never disappear. Make sure you constraints are proper.

Comment: Regardless of text quantity It definitely does disappear if no minimum set.   No constraints error in xcode.  One odd thing is it sets contentview height--if I do not constrain it-- to a very low value.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `sizeToFit` with Autolayout will not have any effect.

You should set the *Vertical Content Compression Resistance Priority* of the label to required. This priority forbids Autolayout to give the label a smaller height as needed to display all lines:

```
[_myLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:1000 
     forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

You may apply this priority in size inspector of interface builder as well.

Comment: And set the label height constraint to >=21, =21, =200 or <=200 or what value?  BTW, currently when I set to <=200, label disappears entirely.

Comment: When I set to <=200, disappears entirely, =200 works for long text but  shows white space with short text, >=21 or =21 shows only first line,

Answer (score 0):

You should add 2 constraint regarding the height of the label:

1. Constraint height <= 200 priority 1000
2. Constraint height >= 21 priority 1000

Comment: This did not change anything

Comment: This work for me.
var constH:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 21);
self.view.addConstraint(constH);

var constH2:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual, toItem: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 200);
self.view.addConstraint(constH2);

Answer (score 0):

Give proper `leading, trailing, top, bottom` constraints to your label and in storyboard set `numberOfLines = 2`. The reason why i specified constraints is that `auto-layout will then automatically resize the intrinsic size of the label` based on the content. Hope, this was helpful.