# IOS/Objective-C: MakeUILabel Flow to Multiple Lines with Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I am trying to get a UILabel to flow to multiple lines and push the elements below it downwards using autolayout.

Here is my code called in viewwillappear.

```
self.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[_myLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:1000
               forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[self.myLabel setNeedsDisplay];
[self.myLabel layoutIfNeeded];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

The UILabel is constrained at the top to the content view and the image below it is constrained to the bottom of the UILabel. The label also has a height constraint of >=21.

On initial load, the label only shows one line.

The weird thing is that after launching a modal VC and the closing it, the label does go to multiple lines but fails to push down the elements below it.

On initial load.

[image]

After launching and canceling modal VC

[image]

I am wondering if the problem has something to do with timing of laying out subviews but have tried almost every thing.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: what about setting .lines in interface builder

Comment: what are your constraints? did you set all the views to be constrained to the top of the main view, or are they constrained to the bottom of the UILabel? have you debugged the view hierarchy at all?

Comment: How is the label constrained on the x axis?

Comment: numberoflines in IB is 0.  There are about 40 constraints.  The label top is constrained to superview.  Then the vertical ones chain everything to the element above it . The bottom element is constrained to the bottom ofthe superview.  It has a priority of 250 so it can be adusted..  On the x axis the label is constrained with leading and trailing.

Comment: I finally found a solution, though not an elegant one: resize manually in didLayoutSubviews.  I created an instance variable for height constraint and set in viewdidlayoutsubviews with: CGSize labelSize = [self.myLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.myLabel.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
    float labelHeight= labelSize.height;
    _myLabelHeight.constant=labelHeight;

Comment: Is this the same question as your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428347/ios-autolayout-make-uilabel-go-to-more-than-one-line-with-autolayout ?

Comment: *"The bottom element is constrained to the bottom ofthe superview. It has a priority of 250 so it can be adusted.."* -- that may be your problem. If you give it a priority of 1000 does auto-layout do what you want? If so, what adjustment are you trying to do that the bottom constraint needs a low priority?

Comment: The bottom height constant is set based on what's in IB.  If the actual text runs long, the idea was to relax that constraint rather than squeeze something else. Whether that's a good idea or not, when I changed it to 1000, no change.  I'm beginning to thing there are some hidden constraints xcode has put in and I need to rebuild everything.

Comment: I guess in theory, the subviews (elements of contentview) are supposed to push the contentview out if you give the contentview height a priority of 250. But I tried this as well without success.

Comment: To do what you want, you need *something* to change height... either the **containing** view, or maybe squeeze the image view? You cannot have an expanding, multi-line label without something else changing.

Comment: I would like the containing view which is called ContentView to adjust.  It is within a scrollview.  Actually my hack above is not fully working because while it spills the label to multiple lines, it turns out that it squeezes other elements below keeping the same element at bottom of starting screen.

Comment: @user6631314 -- Sounds like you are messing with Priorities when you don't need to. Start simple - I'll give you a quick example in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example:

- Create a new ViewController.
- Add a button, constrain 40-pts from the top and centered horizontally
- Add a UIView (green view). Constrain centered horizontally, width of 240, and top-space to button of 20.
- Add two labels to the green view.
- Top label, number of lines = 0, leading and trailing constraints of 16, top constraint of 8 (to green superview)
- Bottom label, centered horizontally, top space to Top label of 8, bottom constraint of 8 (to green superview).
- Connect the Top label to `@IBOutlet var multiLineLabel: UILabel!` in the view controller.
- Connect the button touch-up-inside to the `@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any)` function in the view controller.
- **NO CHANGES to priorities.**

Run the app. Each tap of the button will add text to the top / multi-line label, and it will "push down" the bottom label, which will, in turn, "push down" the bottom edge of the green view.

[image]

```
class ExpandingLabelViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var multiLineLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {

        if let s = multiLineLabel.text {

            multiLineLabel.text = s + " Here is some more text."

        }

    }

}
```

Once you have that working, you can add other elements to the view. Just make sure you have a "chain" of vertical spacing constraints, with the top-most element constrained to the top of the green superview, and the bottom-most element constrained to the bottom of the green superview.

Comment: Your example works.  In my case, I will redo all my constraints as somewhere something has gone awry.